# Google Cloud Container Builder timeout

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

The Google Cloud Container Builder API [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds#Build) says that you are able to set the timeout through the API.

Our build are triggered by webhooks, meaning that the API is irellevant for us. Is there a way to set the build timeout on automatically triggered builds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For build triggers, you can specify the [same parameters as a build resource](https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/config#configuration_file_encoding) in your *cloudbuild.yaml*, which includes the `timeout` parameter. For example:

```
steps:
- name: 'ubuntu'
  args: ['./binary', 'rawdata.tgz']

timeout: 1200s
```

Comment: I'm getting ```ERROR: gcloud crashed (InvalidBuildError): Field [timeout] was provided, but should not have been. You may be using an improper Cloud Build pipeline.```
Hints appreciated!

Comment: If anyone encounters what I did, I finally could move on removing this from the cloudbuild.yaml and instead configuring it with the gcloud command:`gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout 1200`

Answer (score 1):

There are two places to put the time out in the yaml file.....

1. In the build step which is set as a max of 10 minutes by the system
2. In the file which controls the overall build time of the whole file.

The line indent controls this.

No indent then Timeout: 1200s is possible

Build Step indent then max Timeout: 10m0s

Comment: I get `Your build failed to run: failed unmarshalling build config cloudbuild.yaml: unknown field "timout" in google.devtools.cloudbuild.v1.Build` unless I have the `timeout` field nested in one of the build steps.